# How to omit or include paragraph according to a preamble setting?

Tags: preamble

Is it possible by including a command to the preamble to make several paragraphs in different places in the main document to be included or not according to my will?

Comment: Have you tried to define a new command? You could define a command with an argument which would only write down the argument, then you could use that command the write down all the paragraphs which you are not sure to include. If you want to remove all these paragraphs later, you could just modify the definition of the command so that it doesn't write anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifinclmypar
\inclmyparfalse
\newcommand{\includemyparagraphs}{\inclmypartrue}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\ifinclmypar #1 \fi}

\includemyparagraphs

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\myparagraph{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

If you comment out the `\includemyparagraph` command, what is written in `\myparagraph` will not appear.

Comment: Of course I will!

Comment: Thank you, but probably there are better solutions which might appear later

Answer (score 2):

Use the `comment` package. For instance

```
% commentprob.tex  SE 519087 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
%\includecomment{versiona} % print the contents
\excludecomment{versiona} % ignore the contents
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{versiona}
Within version A
\end{versiona}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The package provides a `comment` environment which comments out all that is inside it; read the manual (`> texdoc comment`). It provides other environments which can be configured to either comment out the contents or leave them alone (above as `\excludecomment{...}` and `\includecomment{...}`). I think that it is possible to have several of these switchable environments in case you need to have different controls for different groups of text or code.